# Macroscop SDK С#, как вставить в меню свой пункт?

Tags: c#, sdk

Есть вопрос по Macroscop SDK С#: я пишу плагин-визуализатор, вообще по sdk информации очень мало, и пытаюсь вставить в меню свой пункт, непонятно как это вообще делается? Есть информация что нужно использовать делегат `public RegisterChannelMenuItemHandler RegisterChannelMenuItem`.

Comment: Все спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: Может тогда опубликуете решение в ответе? )